# How to strip off left side of binary number in Python?

Tags: python, binary

I got this binary number `101111111111000`

I need to strip off the 8 most significant bits and have `11111000` at the end.

I tried to make `101111111111000 << 8`, but this results in `10111111111100000000000`, it hasn't the same effect as `>>` which strips the lower bits. So how can this be done? The final result **MUST BE** binary type.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary type"? Python has no such type. Would an integer suffice?

Comment: "it hasn't the same effect as >> which strips the lower bits" is because `>>` does not "strip", but it *shifts* the bits. So it does have the same effect as `<<`, in the other direction.

Comment: Integers are binary yeah, but I'am working in the binary level, that's why i'am approaching it with binaries.

Comment: do you specifically need the 8 left-most bits stripped (irrespective of the word length) or do you really only want the right-most 8 bits?

Comment: @Alnitak It would be more like I need the 8 lower significant bits of any binary number, doesnt matter the word length.

Comment: @RodrigoFormighieri that's a _completely_ different (but far easier) question to answer.   Your question would have made more sense if you had described what you wanted to _retain_ rather than what you want to throw away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the rightmost 8 bits of an integer `n` using bitwise-and:

```
n&255
```

255 is the sum of the values of the smallest 8 bits.

So, starting with `101111111111000`, which is 24568 decimal, `n&255` gives `11111000`, which is 248 decimal.

Comment: this is only consistent with the OP's question if the input data had 16 bits to start with.

Comment: Well possibly. The OP said they wanted to strip the first 8 bits off a 15 bit number, but the output they asked for was 8 bits, so it doesn't seem like that *was* quite what they wanted.

Answer (score 1):

another general way to do this is:

```
n = int('101111111111000', 2) # 24568

n & (1 << int.bit_length(n) - 8) - 1
```

gives 120 (or `1111000`)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this for a number `x` with `n` digits, one can use this

`x&(2**(len(bin(x))-2-8)-1)`

-2 to strip 0b, -8 to strip leftmost

Simply said it `ands` your number with just enough `1`s that the 8 leftmost bits are set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

*Another* general way:

```py
x&(2**n-1)
```

where `x` is the integer and `n` is the number of bits you want to strip.